# Elasticsearch top level query.term and query.bool.must.term: equivalent?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is a top level `term` query exactly the same as one inside a `bool.must`? i.e. are the below equivalent?

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
      "must": {"term": {"object.type": "Event"}}
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query": {
    {"term": {"object.type": "Event"}}
  }
}
```

Are there any top-level clauses when on the top level would behave differently if moved to inside a `bool.must`?

The context: I'm writing a proxy that adds a filter to the queries of certain users, so may be converting the top-level queries to ones inside a `bool`, but with an additional filter.

(I don't have X-Pack available, since similar behaviour is available with X-Pack I believe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this for a while: yes, they are equivalent.